# list control font in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I have following code to set the font in list control:

```
item = wx.ListItem()
font = wx.Font(pointSize=48, family=wx.ROMAN, style=wx.NORMAL, weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD,
               underline=False, face="", encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT
item.SetFont(font)
item.SetText("hello")
self.list.InsertItem(item)
```

When I run the above code, the item will display after a blank item. If I remove the `font = ...` and `item.SetFont(font)` line, the item will display correctly.

Is there anybody can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post more code, something we can copy paste and execute. I tried your code with a new listctrl and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to change the font on all the rows or individually? If you want to do all the rows, then just use the wx.ListCtrl instance's SetFont() method. Otherwise, your method should work. A small runnable example would help us figure this out if you're wanting the latter.